# Flatmapping Optional of collection

Tags: java, lambda

So I have variable `Optional<Collection<Student>>` and I would like to use `.findFirst()` lambda method to find `Student` address.

The way I am doing it right now is this

```
Optional<Collection<Student>> students = ...;
return students.map(s -> s.stream()
                            .filter(...)
                            .findFirst())
                    .orElse(Optional.empty());
```

Is there A better way to do this so I wouldn't have stream inside map?

Comment: I'm curious, why do you have an optional collection? Typically methods should always return a collection, but the collection might be empty.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems like you are looking for [`flatMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#flatMap-java.util.function.Function-):

```
students.flatMap(s -> s.stream()
                       .filter(...)
                       .findFirst());
```

That will map the `Optional<Collection<Student>>` to an `Optional<Student>` instead of an `Optional<Optional<Student>>`.

Comment: Is there a way to unwrap Optional<Collection<Student>> to Stream<Student>?